# Jmeter performance testing :

Tags: jmeter

I have a requested in jmeter that request created new one request, so I need that new one request url in a variable because new one request having a user I'd.

Comment: Not clear with your question. Can you elaborate more details in Step and example?

Comment: 1)  create http request (get)  2) this request creating new one request. I need new one request url

Comment: Response is like a otp page

Comment: on clicking URL to verify the link getting new one URL i want that new one url.   On requesting  "http://mail-find.com/outside.php?aHR0cDovL2Nib3NzLnFhLm9uZS5jZmc6ODAwMC9jYm9zcy9nYXRld2F5Q29udHJvbGxlci91c2VyT25ib2FyZGVkRmlyc3RUaW1lP3VzZXJJZD1yZ1cwdUsyRkZVOTVtdE9YNVk5T1ZnJTNEJTNE"                      Gettng new one request which is "http://cboss.qa.one.cfg:8000/cboss/gatewayController/userOnboardedFirstTime?userId=rgW0uK2FFU95mtOX5Y9OVg%3D%3D
"   i want to extract user id of created new one URL

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this situation in at least 2 ways:

1. Extract the dynamic part using [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor):

   - Add Regular Expression Extractor as a child of the 1st request
   - Configure it as follows:

     - `Field to check:` `URL`
     - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `id`
     - Regular Expression:`userId=(.*)`
     - Template: `$1$`
   - Assuming everything goes well you should be able to refer extracted value as `${id}` where required (manually add it to the end of each and every request)
2. You can semi-automate the process using Using the [HTTP URL Re-writing Modifier](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-http-url-re-writing-modifier), just add it as a child of the first request and put `userId` into "Session Argument Name" input field, JMeter should be smart enough to automatically add these "userId" postfixes to subsequent requests.

Comment: Not able to extract with the 1st one solution, for 2nd one userId will be variable?